# Google Datastore - Search Optimization Technique

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am dealing with a real-estate app. A Home will hvae typical properties like Price, Bed Rooms, Bath Rooms, SqFt, Lot size etc. User will search for Homes and such a query will require multiple inequality filters like: Price between x and y, rooms greater than z, bathrooms more than p... etc.

I know that multiple inequality filters are not allowed. I also do not want to perform any filtering in my code and/because I want to be able to use Cursors.

so I have come up with two solutions. I am not sure if these are right - so wonder if gurus can shed some light

Solution 1: I will discretize the values of each attribute and save them in a list-field, then use IN. For example: If there are 3 bed rooms, instead of storing beds=3, I will store beds = [1,2,3]. Now if a user searches for homes with say at least two bedrooms, then instead of writing the filter as beds>2, I will write the filter as "beds IN [2]" - and my home above [1,2,3] will qualify - so so will any home with 2 beds [1,2] or 4 beds [1,2,3,4] and so on

Solution 2: It is similar to the first one but instead of creating a list-property, I will actually add attributed (columns) to the home. So a home with 3 bed rooms will have the following attributed/columns/properties: col-bed-1:true, col-bed-2:true, col-bed-3:true. Now if a user searches for homes with say at least two bedrooms, then instead of writing the filter as beds>2, I will write the filter as "col-bed-2 = true" - and my home will qualify - so will any home with 2 beds, 3 beds, 4 beds and so on

I know both solutions will work, but I want to know:
1. Which one is better both from a performance and google pricing perspective
2. Is there a better solution to do this?

Comment: this won't work for price unless you limit the precision (say every $50 you discretize)

Answer (score 1):

I do almost exactly your use case with a python gae app that lists posts with housing advertisements (similar to craigslist). I wrote it in python and searching with a filter is working and straightforward.

You should choose a language: Python, Java or Go, and then use the [Google Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/lesson2) (that has built-in filtering for equalities or inequalities) and build datastore indexes that you can query using the search API.

For instance, you can use a python class like the following to populate the datastore and then use the Search API.

```
class Home(db.Model):
    address = db.StringProperty(verbose_name='address')
    number_of_rooms = db.IntegerProperty()
    size = db.FloatProperty()
    added = db.DateTimeProperty(verbose_name='added', auto_now_add=True)  # readonly
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(required=True, auto_now=True)
    timestamp = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)  #
    image_url = db.URLProperty();
```

I definitely think that you should avoid storing permutations for several reasons: Permutations can explode in size and makes the code difficult to read. Instead you should do like I did and find examples where someone else has already solved an equal or similar problem.

[This appengine demo](http://advanced-search-demo.appspot.com/) might help you.

Comment: how big is your data set? Since Google Search API has built in multiple inequalities filters, I wonder how's it performance.

Comment: My indexes are about 1 GB and my data is about 1 GB + blobs that are many GB. I store blobs in the blobstore and the blobs take the most space. Ok, the search is not lightning fast but it works well.